# Loading ActiveX object on Flex application html page

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, activex

I am attempting to load an activex object on the same page where my flex application resides.  Is this possible? Can I have 2 object tags on one page?

As of right now the flex application loads fine but when I attempt to access the activeX control it says its null.  But if I have the same activex control on its own webpage it works perfectly fine.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues was that my browser was caching the page, I realized that once I made a change to the name of the ActiveX object and the error thrown was still referencing the old name of the ActiveX object.  The other error was I had a Var with the same name of the ActiveX object inside the javascript code, that seemed to be causing it to fail, although I am not entirely sure why.  Once I removed that variable the script worked fine.  I had run into that same problem the day before just didn't notice it the second time around, because I have been working on this integration for a few days straight now.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I found the error.  It was a simple error in my javascript code. Turns out it works fine adding another Object tag and loading another activex control. Chalk this up as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you post your mistake, that way we'll all benefit from what you learned - maybe your mistake was common.

Kudos for answering your own question though.  May want to change the title so it says resolved.